# Scrolling text view in custom recycler adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview, scrollview

I am using a custom `RecyclerView` with a custom adapter. Inside the adapter model XML there is a text view with fixed height and width I need to scroll the text inside text view. While scrolling the text view do not scroll the entire `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Please provide some of your code.

Comment: nothing a text view and i need to scroll it.and text view is inside recycler view

Comment: any solution @Joe S

Comment: I'd suggest about the same than the first answer

Answer (score 1):

you could try to wrap your `TextView` with a `NestedScrollView`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: by clicking text view focus is changing to recycler view

Comment: that is different question

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView is not meant for this. What you wanna do is something like this

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is a very very longs text\nThis is a very very longs text\nThis is a very very longs text\nThis is a very very longs text\nThis is a very very longs text\nThis is a very very longs text\nThis is a very very longs text\nThis is a very very longs text\nThis is a very very longs text\nThis is a very very longs text\nThis is a very very longs text\nThis is a very very longs text\nThis is a very very longs text\nThis is a very very longs text\n"/>
</ScrollView>
```

If you persist on having such a TextView inside your RCV – do rethink your design ideas. Vertical inside vertical scroll is a horrible idea.

Comment: Scroll view in side RCV does't work properly.this is done in IOS

Comment: @AswinN have you read my comment in full? A scroll inside another scroll is a design flaw, it should not be implemented in any weird way, don't you think so?